# Approximate function from two dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I have a black and white image that is filtered to contain only the value 0 or 255. The image shows a white line on a black background. As the line is multiple pixels thick the array has columns with multiple non-zero values. 
However, I want to approximate the white line as a function from the image therefore I only want to have one value per column. 
This value should ideally be the median of all the other disregarded pixels. 
I achieved this by retrieving the indices of the non-zero values and get their median setting all of the values of the remaining indices to zero. However, this is a really slow approach is there something more efficient? Another approach was to use np.argmax() which also turned out to be to slow.

```
def multi_valued_threshold(image_data: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return cv.threshold(image_data, 50, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

def one_valued_threshold(image_data: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    data = multi_valued_threshold(img)
    y = data.shape[1]
    for c, d in enumerate(data):
        # print("Before",d)
        # get the median of the row (center of gravity)
        if not np.any(d): continue
        center = np.nonzero(d)
        # center = int(center)
        mark = True
        print(center[0])
        for i in center[0]:
            if mark:
                data[c][i] = 255
                mark = False
            else:
                data[c][i] = 0

        # data[c][data[c] == 255] = 0
        # data[c][int(np.median(center))] = 255
    return data
```

[image: Orignial image (.bmp)]

[image: Goal (achieved by using np.argmax() too slow!)]
[image: Using thresholding]

Comment: Can you give an estimate of what size of an array we are dealing with, and what is slow and what is acceptably fast?

Answer (score 0):

I would do smth like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread('yM5S6.png')
img = img.sum(-1)>0.9

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
plt.imshow(img)

col_idx = np.arange(img.shape[0], 0, -1).astype(float)
col_idxs = col_idx.reshape(-1, 1).repeat(img.shape[1], 1)
col_idxs[(1-img).astype(bool)] = np.nan

data = np.nanmedian(col_idxs, 0)

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
plt.plot(data)
```

Output:
[image]